# How can i put the code in a loop because its not taking the input again

Tags: java

user will enter the row and column of the block. The number of rows and the number of columns should be an integer greater than 2 and less than or equal to 10. If any input is incorrect, show an error message and ask for that input again.

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows ");
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ro = obj1.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns ");
    int co = obj1.nextInt();

    if((ro > 2 && ro <=10)   &&  (co > 2 && co <=10))
    {
        CLASS obj = new CLASS(ro,co);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Erro Wrong ipnut " + "Please enter again");

    }
```

How can i put the above code in a loop because it only runs one time and not taking the input again when the wrong input is entered its just showing the message.

Comment: This is no doubt an exercise. What have you tried? Why did you use all the strange tags?

Comment: You need to enclose the entire input process in a while loop. And what is CLASS? This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there are loops named while and for. Look at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of stupid but here's a quick solution anyways:

```java
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows ");
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ro = obj1.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns ");
    int co = obj1.nextInt();

    if((ro > 2 && ro <=10)   &&  (co > 2 && co <=10)) {
        CLASS obj = new CLASS(ro,co);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error wrong input. Please try again.");
    }
}
```